# My iPhone got stolen and they locked my icloud account. How can regain access to my icloud account to erase my data?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, accounts

My iPhone got stolen and apple locked my iCloud account. I don't have access to the reset email for iphone cause it uses an icloud email address that's on the iPhone and I don't recall the security answer. I  was told to answer the security question and reanswer it every 8 hours to unlock my iCloud account. Is there another way to access my iCloud account to erase my data on there and track my phone? Thank you!

Comment: You can try to reset your password. https://iforgot.apple.com   Then erase your iphone.

Comment: I have no access to the email that would let me reset the password cause that email uses the apple email that's on the my stolen iphone. So, I can't reset the password. But, thank you!

Comment: You should be able set up your email on another mail client with another device like a laptop or tablet. The device doesn’t matter, as long as you know your passwords.